# How to change background color of list items based on their values?

Tags: android, database, listview, user-interface, simplecursoradapter

I have a list of items in a database, which have values of either 0,1 or 2. I have used a simplecursor adapter and an activity which has a listview for the display. Now I want to change the background color of each item to reflect its value i.e I want the background of items with value of 0 to be green, those with value of 1 to be yellow and those with value of 2 to be red. How do i go about this? My adapter and activity are currently having black background.

Comment: Are you asking someone to code if else combination of code for you ?

Comment: no. I was not aware which methods were to be overriden.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create a XML layout file for single list item for list view.
then create a adapter class. in which inflate that xml view.
and inside that adpter in getView() method check for your logic.

here's my adpter class getView()..

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewHolder holder;
      if (convertView == null) {

       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_list_item, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();

       holder.mTxtContactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
       holder.mTxtContactNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber);
       holder.mTxtContactAdd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactAddress);
       holder.mImgCall = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgCall);
       holder.mImgSms = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgSms);

       convertView.setTag(holder);
      } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

        holder.mTxtContactName.setText(list.get(position).getContactName());
        holder.mTxtContactNumber.setText(list.get(position).getContactNumber());
        holder.mTxtContactAdd.setText(list.get(position).getContactAdd());

        holder.mImgSms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("con", "SMS");
                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:"+list.get(position).getContactNumber())); 
                context.startActivity(smsIntent);
            }
        });

        holder.mImgCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel://"+list.get(position).getContactNumber())); 
                context.startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });


     return convertView;
     }

     static class ViewHolder {
      TextView mTxtContactName;
      TextView mTxtContactNumber;
      TextView mTxtContactAdd;
      ImageButton mImgCall;
      ImageButton mImgSms;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of position in `getView()` and do give what background color you want for that indexed row.

Comment: you mean getView() method in BaseArray class?

Comment: in Adapter which you are using. Override adapters getView()

Comment: i am using it in SimpleCursor Adapter. When i changed the getView method only the background of text is getting replaced and its not looking good :(

Comment: @user1971924 so what you want then?

Comment: you can provide your own layout for row n then do the same thing for layouts root view so that the whole row will have background color you want and not only the text.

Comment: ok will try it out and then see .... I was working on fixing bugs in logic part today .... dint try out these suggestions ... will try your suggestions and also the others and get back in a day or two

Answer (score -1):

Have a check inside the getView() of your Adapter as follows

```
if(item.getValue()==0)
   v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
else if(item.getValue()==1)
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
else
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

`item` here are your objects , and `getValue()` is where you have your values 0, 1, 2.